# Difference between parent and main process and how to detect a main process?

Tags: c, fork

Below example I create 3 another process and I have also 1 main process. So totally, there are 4 process which is executing. My question that I can check the which process is parent and which process is child by controlling the return value of the `fork` system call function. However how can I detect the main process execution? And what is the difference between a main process and parent process?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int a =fork(); 
    int b =fork(); 


    if (a == 0) 
        printf("Hello from Child(A)!\n"); 

    // parent process because return value non-zero. 
    else
        printf("Hello from Parent(A)!\n"); 

    if (b == 0) 
        printf("Hello from Child(B)!\n"); 

    // parent process because return value non-zero. 
    else
        printf("Hello from Parent(B)!\n"); 


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: how do you define "main process" ? Do you mean the original process ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code creates 4 processes :

- `(a > 0) && (b > 0)` : the original process
- `(a == 0) && (b > 0)` : the first child process of the original process (child A)
- `(a > 0) && (b == 0)` : the second child process of the original process (child B)
- `(a == 0) && (b == 0)` : the first child process of child A (child AA)

Remember that [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) creates a child process, and returns the pid of this child process in the parent process, and returns 0 in the child process.